# Python and socket - connet to specific path

Tags: python, sockets, kubernetes

I need to connect/send msg to `http://localhost:8001/path/to/my/service`, but I am not able to find how to do that. I know how to send if I only have `localhost` and `8001`, but I need this specific path `/path/to/my/service`. There is where my service is running.

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(<full-url-to-my-service>)
s.sendall(bytes('Message', 'utf-8'))
```

**Update**

My service is running on `localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/my_namespace/services/my_service:http/proxy`. How can I connect to it with **python**?

Comment: do you want to achieve this only by using socket API in python? Since this is a HTTP request, modules like requests are more tailored for such requests(ie HTTP requests) and also they have good documentation and abstract away a lot of information which you might have to implement in your code using socket API for more complex HTTP requests.

Comment: `socket` is primitive object and it doesn't have specialized method for this - and you have to on your own create message with correct data. You have to learn HTTP protocol and use it to send `GET /path/to/my/service` - `s.sendall(bytes('GET /path/to/my/service\r\n\r\n', 'utf-8'))` with two `\r\n` (new lines) at the end to inform server that it is end of message.

Comment: better try with `requests`, `urllib`, `httpx`, which are specialized to work with HTTP protocol.

Comment: Sorry. Yes i need to send a http request, you are right. I didn't see that. Thx

Answer (score 1):

As @furas told in the comments

> socket is primitive object and it doesn't have specialized method for this - and you have to on your own create message with correct data. You have to learn HTTP protocol and use it to send

This is a sample snippet to send a GET request in python using requests library

```
import requests
URL = 'http://localhost:8001/path/to/my/service'
response_text = requests.get(URL).text
print(response_text)
```

This assumes the Content-Type that GET URL produces is text. If it is json, then a minor change is required

```
import requests
URL = 'http://localhost:8001/path/to/my/service'
response_json = requests.get(URL).json()
print(response_json)
```

There are other ways to achieve the same using other good frameworks like urllib, and so on.
[Here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) is the documentation of requests library for reference

Answer (score -1):

`sendall()` requires `bytes`, so `String` must be encoded.

```
s.sendall("foobar".encode())
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but this is not what i was intended. I need to send the message to specific path "/path/to/my/service".

Comment: A socket is assigned each *ONE* combination of one IP address and one port,  but not a path, so sockets can't distinguish "http://localhost:8080/" and "http://localhost:8080/foo/bar". If you want to serve different service in localhost, must change port number.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not able to change, where my service is running

Comment: Path of URL is matter of application layer (HTTP), but socket is matter of session layer and transport layer (TCP/UDP). Before using socket, I recommend studying basics of how network works.

Comment: This was a simple server client (not HTTP) that i was running on my local machine. But i wanted to run the server in kubernetes with the access through kubectl proxy. But you are right, now i need to send a http request.

Comment: Please add information about using kubernetes And write details at once as you can but not tidbit.